# using stokes theorem to calculate a line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use stokes theorem to show that:

$$\int_c ydx + zdy +xdz = -\sqrt{3} \pi a^2$$

Where c is the suitably oriented intersection of the surfaces $x^2 + y^2 +z^2=a^2$ and the plane $x+y+z=0$.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yeah the curl of F is $(-1,-1,-1)$ and i have dotted this with the normal to the sphere in spherical coordinates but i do not know how to get the parameter domain when the sphere is parameterised in spherical coordinates

Comment: Don't understand why the question has 3 up-votes... does it show research effort and an attempt at answering the question??